# Change the order of user login process with Azure ADFS Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, adfs

I have an MVC  5 application that lets users Single Sign On using Azure ADFS.  Currently, when users first navigate to the application site, they see the Azure Portal login page (SSO) as default.  That is not what our company wants.  We would like the **order** of user log in process like:

First, users should see our own company custom themed page. In that custom themed page, there are some custom logos and company business texts and a Log-In button.  When the Log-In button is pressed, users should see the Azure Portal login page (SSO) and log in from there.

Please give me some ideas how to achieve so.  Thank you  in advance.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286844/exclude-specific-path-from-wif-authorization-in-a-asp-net-mvc-4-project) might be useful but it's rather more involved than I'd hope. It might be simpler just to create an outer website/virtual directory which has anonymous access, and then the login page will be a link to the inner, authenticated website which would redirect to Azure if the user wasn't already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Azure ADFS"? Do you mean "Azure Active Directory"?

To customize AAD, refer: [Add company branding to your Sign In and Access Panel pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn532270.aspx).

Note that this requires AAD Premium and you will go directly to the page - no way to have a Login button page first.